# Is there a way to output TCPDump to a file, and filter it with Java, overwriting the file every 5 seconds with new data?

Tags: java, mysql, raspbian, tcpdump

I am configuring a raspberry pi 3 to count the number of wifi capable devices within range of the wireless card I am using, and save that value to a database. This value needs to be updated every 5 seconds. In order to get an accurate number, without any extra information after processing, I would like to use Java to delete extra packets with the same MAC Address, delete any probe-request packets from iPhones (as they randomize MAC Addresses), count up the different MAC Addresses, and then delete everything in the file but that final number. I am not looking for a complete answer or guide on how to do this, just anything that you think might help me.

In short, how can I update a file every 5 seconds with the output of TCPDump, and filter that data with Java?

I can at this point properly capture wireless data with TCPDump, but I am unsure of how to properly filter and normalize this data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please note that Stack Overflow can help you with your code but will not write it for you (i.e. please post what you have).

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can do everything !

first read `man tcpdump` and you will discover these wonderfull options .

- `-G rotate_seconds`
- `-w file`

this command will create a new file in `/tmp/` every 2 seconds

```
tcpdump -n -i ens18 -w /tmp/foobar.%s.pcap -G 2 -C 100 not port 22
```